# Reading number from string containing ' '

Tags: string, matlab

I would like to read the number 2 from the following char:

```
'mc_parameters.E_i = '2';'
```

So far, the `' '` around the number makes it a mess, because what MATLAB sees when I try to use `sscanf`, `textscan` and `str2num` is

```
'mc_parameters.E_i = '2';'
```

and it doesn't recognize the last `';'` as a string in itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: So is it `mc_parameters.E_i = '2'` or `'2'` that you want to extract the 2 from?

Comment: The entire line, so just using str2num won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this functon :

```
myNum = str2num(myString);
```

The documentation about [str2num](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html)

**EDIT**

I miss understood something there another thing to add :

```
myString = 'mc_parameters.E_i = '2';';
temp = sscanf(myString,['%[A-z.] %3c %d']);
extractNumberInString = temp(end); % Because last scanf is %d for double number.
```

Maybe you need to convert myString like this to execute the example :

```
myString = 'mc_parameters.E_i = ''2'';';
```

**EDIT 2**

Better solution is to use `textscan` because with `%*` you can skip some char like this :

```
test = textscan(myString,'%*[^''] %*c %d'); 
% Search until first ' and look for the white space and finish with the double number
```

Answer (score 0):

you gave to use   `str2num`

```
str = '2';

x = str2num(str)
```

output

```
x = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean, but this one-liner works for all interpretations of your question I could think of (and then some):

```
cellfun(@str2double, regexp(str, ...
    '[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*(e|E|d|D)?[+-]?[0-9]*', 'match'));
```

where `str` is your string to extract the number from.

This regular expression will find and convert all numbers in the string, in any of the following forms:

- 2
- +2.05
- 21.05
- -2.0755e-4
- -0.0755D4
- ...

NOTE: if you only need to extract integers, a simple `'[0-9]*'` will suffice :)

Examples:

```
>> format short e
>> f = @(str) cellfun(@str2double, regexp(str, '[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*(e|E|d|D)?[+-]?[0-9]*', 'match'));
>> 
>> str = 'mc_parameters.E_i = ''2.04'';  +-8.4e-005';
>> f(str)
ans = 
    2.0400e+000    -8.400e-005

>> str = '2.18';
>> f(str)
ans = 
    2.1800e+000

>> str = '''2.21''; ''2..3e-4';
>> f(str)
ans = 
    2.2100e+000    2.0000e+000    3.0000e-004
```